# Cascading combobox with one extra item

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I created two comboboxes, one for categories and one for items. What I want is when the category changes, the items will also be changed. Here is my XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="ComboBoxTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="100" Width="202">
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="171"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding CategoryList}"
                  DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCategory}"/>
        <ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,29,0,0" Name="comboBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="171"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ItemList}"
                  DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And here is the codebehind:

```
namespace ComboBoxTest
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private List<Categories> _CategoryList = new List<Categories>();
    private List<Items> _ItemList = new List<Items>();

    private Categories _SelectedCategory;
    private Items _SelectedItem;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        _CategoryList.Add(new Categories(1, "Car"));
        _CategoryList.Add(new Categories(2, "Truck"));
        _CategoryList.Add(new Categories(3, "Motorcycle"));
        SelectedCategory = _CategoryList[0];
    }

    public List<Categories> CategoryList
    {
        get { return _CategoryList; }
    }
    public List<Items> ItemList
    {
        get { return _ItemList; }
    }

    public Categories SelectedCategory
    {
        get { return _SelectedCategory; }
        set 
        { 
            _SelectedCategory = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedCategory");
            UpdateItems();
            OnPropertyChanged("ItemList");
        }
    }
    public Items SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _SelectedItem; }
        set
        {
            _SelectedItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
        }
    }

    private void UpdateItems()
    {
        _ItemList.Clear();

        switch (_SelectedCategory.ID)
        {
            case 1:
                _ItemList.Add(new Items("BMW"));
                break;
            case 2:
                _ItemList.Add(new Items("Ford"));
                break;
            case 3:
                _ItemList.Add(new Items("Harley"));
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Something is wrong");
                break;
        }
        if (_ItemList.Count != 0)
        {
            SelectedItem = _ItemList[0];
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

public class Categories
{
    private int _ID;
    private string _Name;

    public Categories(int id, string name)
    {
        _ID = id;
        _Name = name;
    }

    public int ID
    {
        get { return _ID; }
        set { _ID = value; }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set { _Name = value; }
    }
}

public class Items
{
    public string _Name;

    public Items(string name)
    {
        _Name = name;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set { _Name = value; }
    } 
}
}
```

At first glance, it seems fine. When I change from Car to Truck, the item list changes from BMW to Ford. The problem is if I expend the item list then change the category, the item list for the new category will have the item from the previous category. I cannot fix this problem. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use `ObservableCollection` instead of simple `List<>`.

```
    private ObservableCollection<Categories> _CategoryList = new ObservableCollection<Categories>();
    private ObservableCollection<Items> _ItemList = new ObservableCollection<Items>();

    private Categories _SelectedCategory;
    private Items _SelectedItem;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        _CategoryList.Add(new Categories(1, "Car"));
        _CategoryList.Add(new Categories(2, "Truck"));
        _CategoryList.Add(new Categories(3, "Motorcycle"));
        SelectedCategory = _CategoryList[0];
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Categories> CategoryList
    {
        get { return _CategoryList; }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Items> ItemList
    {
        get { return _ItemList; }
    }
```

OR you will have to raise the `PropertyChanged` for your `ItemList` from `UpdateItems()` methods after you are done updating the `ItemList`.

Comment: Thanks. Changing the List to ObservableCollection solves the problem. I also tried the 2nd suggestion by moving the ``OnPropertyChanged("ItemList")`` to the end of UpdateItems(), but it doesn't work.
Why favor ObservableCollection in this case?

Comment: If we are binding collection to the UI and we know it is going to change during the coarse of application it is beneficial to use ObservableCollection as it provides automatic collectionchanged notification to the UI....or else we will have to raise the change events on every add/remove operation on the collection